# Grid or relative layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to have a page in an app have multiple buttons (in grid fashion) I was wondering if it would be better to populate a grid layout with buttons or manually add buttons to a relative layout, or if it even matters. I want each button to do something different so if using a grid layout is better  how would I do this. I know you need to have `gridview.setOnItemClickListener` but that would make each button do the same thing (I think). Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: As you add buttons to the gridview, you would call button.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of buttons, use a RelayiveLayout or TableLayout.  If you have an unknown number of buttons and want to be able to scroll through them, that's the time to use a GridView.